# How to allow all third party in chrome using javascript or python?

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, third-party-cookies

Is it possible to do following operation using javascript or python?

Enter this in url box. `chrome://settings/cookies`

In cookies and other site data -> General settings -> Allow all cookies

Comment: What have you tried and researched so far?

Comment: I searched enough and didn't get any satisfactory result. I guess, it is not possible to do this operation through code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ypu can do something like this. Just need to find out exact xapth element.
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\temp\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('chrome://settings/cookies')
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("<xpath locator>").click()
```

Comment: I am not asking about using selenium chrome driver. I have asked for normal chrome browser.